# generalization of conservative vector field to matrices

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, hessian-matrix

Suppose we are given a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is $[f(x_1, x_2), g(x_1, x_2)]^T$. We want to know that if this vector is the gradient of any smooth function $H(x_1, x_2)$ i.e. a conservative vector field. Then we know that if  second derivatives commute, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1} \quad \textrm{or in other words } \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} =  \frac{\partial^2 H}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}
$$
the vector $[f(x_1, x_2), g(x_1, x_2)]^T$ is $\textbf{actually}$ the gradient of a function.

My question is, can we generalize to Hessian matrices? Suppose now we are given a matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
a(x_1, x_2) & b(x_1, x_2)\\
c(x_1, x_2) & d(x_1, x_2)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
instead of a vector. We want to know if this matrix is the hessian of any smooth function $H(x_1, x_2)$. Can we say that if the third derivatives commute i.e.:
$$
\frac{\partial a}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial c}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial b}{\partial x_1} \quad \textrm{or in other words } \frac{\partial^3 H}{\partial x_1 \partial x_1 \partial x_2} = \frac{\partial^3 H}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1 \partial x_1} = \frac{\partial^3 H}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2 \partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial b}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial d}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial c}{\partial x_2} \quad \textrm{or in other words } \frac{\partial^3 H}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2 \partial x_2} = \frac{\partial^3 H}{\partial x_2 \partial x_2 \partial x_1} = \frac{\partial^3 H}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1 \partial x_2}
$$
the matrix $M$ is $\textbf{actually}$ the Hessian of a function.

If yes, can you point me some references?